# Retrieve table names from sqlite3 database with php

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a working version of this code as below which the result [can be seen here](http://sandybeachit.x10.mx/hosting/sinderbox/test2.php).

```
<?php
// Display all sqlite tables
    $db = new SQLite3('data.db');
    $tablesquery = $db->query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';");

    while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        echo $table['name'] . ' <br />';
    }
?>
```

The issue is I only have two tables in this database `USERS` and `ADMIN_LOGIN` but I am getting `sqlite_sequence` appearing. Is there a way I can only show the table names and not `sqlite_sequence`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use PHP to check if the table is named `sqlite_sequence`, and if it isn't then output the table's name.

```
<?php
// Display all sqlite tables
    $db = new SQLite3('data.db');
    $tablesquery = $db->query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';");

    while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        if ($table['name'] != "sqlite_sequence") {
            echo $table['name'] . ' <br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What about changing your initial query to ignore `sqlite_sequence` as a `name != 'sqlite_sequence` condition?

```
// Display all sqlite tables
$db = new SQLite3('data.db');
$sql = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence';";
$tablesquery = $db->query($sql);

while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    echo $table['name'] . ' <br />';
}
```

Or you can skip all tables with `sqlite*` prefix like this using `NOT LIKE`:

```
// Display all sqlite tables
$db = new SQLite3('data.db');
$sql = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite%';";
$tablesquery = $db->query($sql);

while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    echo $table['name'] . ' <br />';
}
```

Comment: You should skip all tables beginning with `sqlite_` (such as the `sqlite_statX` tables).